# pm2 status doesn't show the running apps using GitLab runner

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, yaml, pm2

I have some react apps running on my server using pm2 (manually)
Now I'am working on Auto Deploy using GitLab Runner
everything's working fine with the deployment except that when I want to stop the apps running with GitLab runner (Auto deployment) they don't show up in `pm2 status` output and they keep running in the background

This is my yml file :

```
stages: 
  - deploy
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - pm2 start node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js -n myapp -f
```

Comment: please elaborate your questions

Comment: i have edited my question, hope it's clear now ?